# Can I get rid of MySql container completly

Tags: ddev

With DDEV, I'm developing with Laravel a project and I use Sqlite for local so I don't really need a proper Database available.

Is there any way to take out of formula the db container completely?

My final goal is to save battery usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. Set `omit_containers: [db,dba]` in either your project or global configuration. `ddev config --omit-containers=db,dba`

Docs at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/configuration/config/#omit_containers

Comment: DDEV - Dream tool ♡

Comment: In DDEV v1.22.0, PhpMyAdmin is going away, so `dba` will be obsolete, it will just be `omit_containers[db]` for this answer